# SetMargin Not Working in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, margin

drawer.xml;  have RelativeLayout id:relative.

I want to show another relative layout on the drawerlayout;

```
RelativeLayout drawer = (RelativeLayout) getApplicationContext().findViewById(R.id.drawerrelative);

RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.relative, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relative));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
drawer.addView(view, params);
```

I show relative layout(id:relative) on main layout(id:drawerrelative) and CENTER on screen.Everythings normally but when i set margin ;

```
params.setMargins(0, 100, 0, 0);
```

not working. I was add view.requestLayout() but not working..

How i can solve this problem? (Thank you and sory for my bad english)

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means to you.

Comment: i show the layout on center screen, but i want to set margin top because i want show the layout center screen and few px near the bottom

Answer (score -1):

Try this code block

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
relativeParams.setMargins(0, 100, 0, 0);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(view);
relativeLayout.requestLayout();
```